# Solving an Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential question:

$\displaystyle \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right )=x+y$

My Attempt:

$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=\sin(x+y)$
$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle Put\; x+y=t \\
\displaystyle 1+\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx} \\
\displaystyle \frac{dt}{dx}-1=\sin t \\
\displaystyle \frac{dt}{dx}=1+\sin t \\
\displaystyle \frac{dt}{1+\sin t}=dx \\
\end{align}$$
Integrating

$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle \int \frac{dt}{1+\sin t}=\int dx
\end{align}$$
Divide both numerator and denominator by $\displaystyle  \cos t $ 
$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle \int \frac{\sec t dt}{\sec t+\tan t}=\int dx
\end{align}$$
Put $\displaystyle  \sec t+\tan t=z $
$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle \sec t\tan t dt+\sec^2 t dt=dz \\
\displaystyle \sec t(\tan t+\sec t) dt=dz \\
\displaystyle \sec t dt=\frac{dz}{z} \\
\end{align}$$

So the integral becomes $\displaystyle \int \frac{dz}{z^2}=\int dx $

$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle -\frac{1}{z}=x+c \\
\displaystyle -\frac{1}{\tan t+\sec t}=x+c \\
\displaystyle -\frac{1}{\tan(x+y)+\sec(x+y)}=x+c \\
\end{align}$$

I am stuck here. The given solution is $\displaystyle tan(x+y)=sec(x+y)+x+c $

Please help.

Comment: You are close. Use $\int\frac{dt}{1+\sin t}=\frac2{\cot\frac t2+1}$, which will allow you to find an explicit form $y=f(x)$.

Comment: I dint get this ..

Comment: The given solution is an implicit equation $f(x,y)=0$, not so handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did the hardest and I'm almost ashamed to write an answer:
\begin{eqnarray*}
-\frac{1}{\tan(t) + \sec(t)} &=& -\frac{\sec(t) - \tan(t)}{\sec^2(t) - \tan^2(t)}\\
&=& \cos^2(t)\frac{\tan(t) - \sec(t)}{1 - \sin^2(t)}\\
&=& \tan(t) - \sec(t)
\end{eqnarray*}

Letting $t = x+y$ yields your answer.